# reflectable 0.3.4 - new version throwing exception

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I just updated my dart application and did a pub cache repair afterwards.

The application does not run and debug throws the following exception

```
Uncaught Unhandled exception:
Unsupported operation: Cannot provide `reflectedType` of instance of generic type 'List'.
#0      InstantiatedGenericClassMirrorImpl.reflectedType (package:reflectable/src/reflectable_transformer_based.dart:713:5)
#1      _getPropertyInfoForType (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_descriptor.dart:210:46)
#2      _buildPropertiesObject.<anonymous closure> (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_descriptor.dart:58:24)
#3      _HashVMBase&MapMixin&&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:340)
#4      _buildPropertiesObject (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_descriptor.dart:56:16)
#5      createPolymerDescriptor (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_descriptor.dart:26:19)
#6      PolymerRegister.initialize (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_register.dart:19:36)
#7      loadInitializers.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:initialize/src/static_loader.dart:46:32)
#8      _runInitQueue (package:initialize/initialize.dart:35:24)
#9      _runInitQueue.<anonymous closure> (package:initialize/initialize.dart:38:26)
#10     _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1149)
#11     _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:502)
#12     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:585)
#13     _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:376)
#14     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:430)
#15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43)
#16     _microtaskLoopEntry (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52)
#17     _ScheduleImmediateHelper._handleMutation (dart:html:49254)
#18     MutationObserver._create.<anonymous closure> (dart:html:27526)
  (anonymous function)
```

The application was running quite well before. 
Possible bug?

Thanks
Teddy

Comment: What kind of application? The most recent reflectable package doesn't work with the most recent analyzer package. Do you use `dependency_overrides` in your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Hi Gunter. Sorry - polymer-dart 1.x application - index.html run in debug mode. Only dependency override is dependency_overrides:
  logging: '0.11.2'

Comment: I have limited the package to reflectable: '0.3.3' and the following changes were made on update - > source_gen 0.4.6 (was 0.4.5+1), < reflectable 0.3.3 (was 0.3.4) (0.3.4 available), > analyzer 0.26.3 (was 0.26.1+14). The application now runs normally, so I have to conclude that reflectable: '0.3.4' has a problem.

Comment: Related Polymer issue https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/651

Answer (score 2):

Rather long story, please check https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/651 for some details, and for the resolution of this issue as it unfolds.